# pst-ode, magnetic induction line

Tags: pstricks

Try to plot a simplified plot of the magnetic field.

The results are as follows:

Looks flawed (looks like T_T)

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-math}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=3cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.2,-1.2)(2.1,1.1)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,subticks=20,
        Ox=-2,Oy=-1](-2,-1)(2,1)
\psset{arrows=->, algebraic}
\psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](-1.9,-0.9)(1.9,0.9){%
(y*(  sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3) - sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3)  )
)/(
(x+1.3)*sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3) - (x-1.3)*sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3)
)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

So, I hope to be able to fix the length of the vector, but I only know the options like 'linewidth' ...

Comment: The tags tikz-pgf and tikz-arrows are wrong. You are using pstricks and not tikz.

Answer (score 1):

There are some singularities. Use three intervals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-ode}

\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=3}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.2,-1.2)(-0.5,1.1)
    \psset{arrows=->, algebraic}
    \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-2,-1)(2,1)}
    \psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](-1.9,-0.9)(-1.405,0.9){%
        (y*(  sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3) - sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3)))
        /
        ((x+1.3)*sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3)-(x-1.3)*sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3))}
    \psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](-1.25,-0.9)(1.3,0.9){%
        (y*(sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3) - sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3)))
        /
        ((x+1.3)*sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3)-(x-1.3)*sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3))}
    \psVectorfield[linecolor=black!60](1.43,-0.9)(2,0.9){%
        (y*(sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3) - sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3)))
        /
        ((x+1.3)*sqrt(((x-1.3)^2+y^2)^3)-(x-1.3)*sqrt(((x+1.3)^2+y^2)^3))}
    \endpsclip
    \psaxes[ticksize=0 4pt,axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=inner,
    subticks=20, Ox=-2,Oy=-1](-2,-1)(2,1)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]